# Babel runtime configuration with webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I installed babel-runtime and tried the following configurations:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel?optional=runtime"
      }
    ]
  },
```

and:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          optional: ['runtime']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

However, it's not working as I'm getting `var sym = _Symbol();` instead of `var sym = _core.Symbol()`, with no references to core-js.

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with setting optional as array ?

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel?optional[]=runtime"
  }
]},
```